# Recargar tabla solo una vez con Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, java, setinterval

Estoy tratando de que mi página se refresque solo una vez para que se actualice después de que se cree un permiso al usuario y solo quiero que se refresque la tabla.

Lo he estado intentando, pero se recarga en bucle infinito y necesito que solo lo haga una vez, que el `setInterval` se ejecute solo una vez

```
<script>
    var contador = 0;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var refresch = setInterval(function () {
            if (contador == 0) {
                $("#IDRELOAD").load($Permisos.init(".$_SESSION['proyecto_actual']."));
                contador = contador + 1;
            }
            if (contador == 1) {
                $("#IDRELOAD").load();
                clearInterval(refresch);
            }
        }, 1000);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: ¿Por qué usar `setInterval` en lugar de `setTimeout`, este se ejecuta solo una vez.

Comment: me pasa lo mismo al quererlo hacer de manera automatica el setTimeout me crea un bucle

Comment: Entonces probablemente estás recargando toda la página y no solo la tabla, no hay otra razón para que se repita con `setTimeout`

Answer (score 0):

Solo agrega un botón que vaya a la misma página, y eso la refresca o recarga.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//$("#Boton").click(function () {
        window.location.href = 'mismaPagina.html';
//    });
});
```

Comment: hola, y de manera automática sin tener que tocar un botón.?